# ini4j character encoding

Tags: java, character-encoding, ini4j

I'am using library `ini4j` for work with `ini` file's.
My problem is, when i make a `ini` file:

```
 try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("path" + ".ini", "UTF-8")) {    
        writer.println("[Main_Menu]");
        writer.println("TEST = Příliš žluťoučký kůň úpěl ďábelské ódy");           
}
```

I cannot read correctly a `String` and i have charset problem.

Read:

```
Ini ini = new Ini();
ini.load(new FileReader(new File("path" + ".ini")));
Ini.Section section = (Section) ini.get("Main_Menu");
System.out.println("\u0020" + section.get("TEST"));
```

Can you help me? How to read correctly?
(in path.ini file **is** correctly string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of FileReader you need to use new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(...), "UTF-8").